# How to perform semantic analysis using a relation tree in order to filter offensive content without affecting the readability in Python

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, stanford-nlp, semantic-analysis

I am trying to create a Webapp for Facebook which would filter the offensive posts and comments without affecting its readability.I am done with POS tagging and I got a relation tree using the Stanford parser.Now I am trying to figure out if there is any inbuilt function in python which would provide me grammatical rules.

For example 1:You are an idiot!

example 2:You are sweet but stupid.

In example 1, if I remove the word idiot it will make the sentence meaningless,however in example 2 if we remove "but stupid" the meaning of sentence won't change even after filtering

**I got few rules in a paper:**

1) POS tag node rule: IF {its previous noun is removable} THEN {POS tag node will be removable}

2) conj tag node rule: IF {both neighbor nodes are removable} THEN {conjunction node will be removable}

3) ADVP-VP rule: IF {the current non-leaf node has only two child nodes; one is ADVP node and the other is VP
node} THEN { IF {ADVP node is removable} THEN {VP node will not be affected}; IF {VP
node is removable} THEN {ADVP node will also be removable}; }

But I didn't find all the rules and there are 55 types of dependency relations so am I supposed to code my own rules??

Comment: _“however in example 2 if we remove "but stupid" the meaning of sentence won't change even after filtering”_ - of course it would, now you are just sweet, before you were sweet and stupid - if that’s not different meanings to you, then I don’t know what possibly could be.

Comment: @CBroe Actually the aim of making this Webapp is to filter out abusive or offensive words without affecting the non offensive words or sentence.So it will act like a firewall which won't allow any offensive or abusive word.I have actually mentioned a wrong example here's a better one .Original:If you ******* hate her,why the **** are you commenting on her.After filteration:If you hate her,why are you commenting on her.....something like this